# Pycharm: How do I use a font installed in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

I am currently using pycharm, and I also have `monaco` installed in my ubuntu. But I cannot find an option of the `monaco` font in my pycharm settings.
Are there any methods to enable this `monaco` font in my *Pycharm*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that font unicode? if not find a unicode version and drop it in $JDK_HOME/jre/lib/fonts and it should work.

Keep me updated